# Group login logs by user ID and date/time

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in MySQL 5.7 similar to the following:

```
id | userid | loginDateTime
—————————————————————————————————
1  |   1    | 2018-08-23 22:01:00
2  |   2    | 2018-08-23 22:01:05
3  |   1    | 2018-08-24 15:01:00
4  |   3    | 2018-08-24 15:01:25
5  |   1    | 2018-08-28 18:01:34
6  |   2    | 2018-08-28 18:01:34
7  |   3    | 2018-08-28 18:01:37
```

I need to get a list of user ID’s that logged in around the same time on a per-day basis. “Around the same time” is defined as in the range of 5 seconds of another user.

In the table above:

On the 23rd, users 1 and 2 logged in around the same time because their login time was between 5 seconds of each other.

On the 24th, users 1 and 3 both logged in but not around the same time, because their logins are more than 5 seconds apart.

On the 28th, all three users logged in around the same time.

Is there any way to get this “per day” report of which users logged in at around what time?

So far, I have the following, but this does not help me get to the results:

SELECT * FROM logs l1, l2 WHERE l1.userid <> l2.userid AND ABS(DATEDIFF(l1.loginDateTime, l2.loginDateTime)) <= 5

Ideally, I would want something like the following:

```
userids | loginDateTime
—————————————————————————————
1, 2    | 2018-08-23 22:01:00
1, 2, 3 | 2018-08-28 18:01:34
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, you could use `join` to get the matches and then aggregate by the first:

```
select t1.loginDateTime, group_concat(distinct t2.userid)
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t2.loginDateTime >= t1.loginDateTime and
        t2.loginDateTime < t1.loginDateTime + interval 5 second and
        t2.userid <> t1.userid
group by t1.loginDateTime;
```

Answer (score 0):

The 5-second range of other users is unreasonable when the large system has many users.
I suggest group records by DateTime ignoring the "seconds".
like this:

```
SELECT group_concat(distinct t1.userid) as userids,  date_format(t1.loginDateTime,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00') as loginDateTime 
FROM t t1,t t2 
WHERE t1.userid <> t2.userid
group by loginDateTime;
```